# Mapping Map<Interface,Interface> with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm

Hey people, i have a the following map* which is giving me lots of trouble:

```
Map<MetricSourceInterface, AliasesInterface>
```

MetricSourceInterface is an entity with simple properties.
AliasesInterface is an entity with only an Id and a list of strings.

Hibernate is creating the database schema so theres no problem with changing it whatsoever.

On a side-note, this is a sub problem from trying to map:

```
Map<MetricSourceInterface, List<String>>
```

Does anyone know the proper way to solve this?

Theres only one limitation for this, i dont want to create an UserType for AliasesInterface or List

Thx in advance :)

---

*edited with pstanton's correction :)

Comment: a 'Map' is not a 'Collection'

Comment: @pstanton - map is not a collection in the sense that `java.util.Map` does not extend `java.util.Collection` interface. `Map` **is**, however, part of "Java Collections" framework and `Map` is most certainly a collection from Hibernate's standpoint - same persister / loader, etc...

Comment: This is not a good question title.

Comment: @cherouvim you are correct. title changed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as `AliasesInterface` is indeed an **entity** in Hibernate sense, there's really no problem with mapping this:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=AliasInterface.class)
@MapKeyManyToMany(targetEntity=MetricSourceInterface.class,  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="metric_source_id"))
private Map<MetricSourceInterface, AliasesInterface> myMap;
```

Note that the above assumes that both `AliasInterface` and `MetricSourceInterface` are entities; if they are indeed interfaces you'll need to refer to their concrete implementations instead.

Keep in mind that `@MapKeyManyToMany` is Hibernate extesion to JPA. More details / examples on [mapping collections are in Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections).

**Update**: The same approach using XML mapping files:

```
<map name="myMap">
  <key column="owner_id"/> <!-- FK to owner entity table -->
  <map-key-many-to-many column="metric_source_id" class="MetricSourceInterface"/>
  <one-to-many class="AliasesInterface"/>
</map>
```

There are [more details here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) and [other examples here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ternary).

Comment: yes, im working with their concrete implementations as you commented. 

can you please, if its not much trouble, translate the annotations to hbm sintax please? im not familiar with them.